# Git based package manager/installer for Linux

Tags: linux, package-management, git, distribution-choice, distributions

Is there any linux distro that has a git based package manager/installer. I want something similar to FreeBSD Ports (which is CVS based, I think) or Mac OS X [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (git based).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [Exherbo](http://exherbo.org/), which uses multiple Git repositories to store its exheres (its term for build recipes similar to Gentoo's ebuilds or BSD's ports).  It's still a pretty young distribution, though.

**Update:** [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/) recently [moved to Git for its package repository](https://www.gentoo.org/news/2015/08/12/git-migration.html).  However, I don't think it's set up yet to have normal users get updates via Git (although I believe it's planned to allow that).

Answer (score 3):

[Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Welcome), a fork of Gentoo, uses a Git-based portage tree.  Gentoo's ebuilds are periodically imported, so you still get all the advantages of its wonderful ebuild collection.

Answer (score 1):

You mention homebrew specifically; linuxbrew is a fork of homebrew aimed at linux.  Deets here: http://linuxbrew.sh/

Answer (score -1):

Try [stali](http://sta.li/), a [suckless](http://suckless.org/) Linux distribution following KISS principle.

Comment: I've edited your question to include relevant links but to properly answer this question, you should edit it yourself to include some details about the distribution's package management.